# How to use GetLastError() in VC++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-c++, error-handling

Making the conversion from Java to c++ isn't easy so help me guys.

i want to see if i'm getting an Access_Error violation in this code:

```
BOOL didThisFail = FALSE;

if (CopyFile(L"MyApplication.exe", szPath, didThisFail))
    cout << "File was copied" << endl;
```

Comment: There's something wrong with `szPath`.  Show the code that declares and initializes it.

Comment: Hans you were right. szPath was only a path (c:\project) and not c:\project\something.exe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (CopyFileW(L"MyApplication.exe", szPath, didThisFail))
{
    std::cout << "File was copied" << std::endl;
}
else if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
{
    std::cout << "Can't do that." << std::endl;
}
else
{
    DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
    //You have to cache the value of the last error here, because the call to
    //operator<<(std::ostream&, const char *) may cause the last error to be set
    //to something else.
    std::cout << "General failure. GetLastError returned " << std::hex
    << lastError << ".";
}
```

Comment: Works.. i'm getting the "can't do that" but i don't know why.. i'm not copying to a special folder

Comment: @Malfist: The OP specifically asked for one kind of error. If you want to recieve a system defined error string you can use the FormatMessage API, as done [here](https://bitbucket.org/BillyONeal/pevfind/src/52c5c4ba45f4/pevFind/Win32Exception.cpp#cl-35).

Comment: @Tom: Check DACLs on both the source and the target. Check to ensure the target is not readonly. Otherwise I don't have much advice. Keep in mind that unless your application is running elevated, it has significantly weaker permissions than it would otherwise have.

Comment: Lol Billy the problem was that i tried to copy a Path and not szPath\\something.exe

Answer (score 0):

There's an example on MSDN's website: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680582(v=vs.85).aspx

```
void ErrorExit(LPTSTR lpszFunction) 
{ 
    // Retrieve the system error message for the last-error code

    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );

    // Display the error message and exit the process

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR)); 
    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, 
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"), 
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf); 
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK); 

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
    ExitProcess(dw); 
}
```

Comment: From MSDN, "Functions executed by the calling thread set this value by calling the SetLastError function. You should call the GetLastError function immediately when a function's return value indicates that such a call will return useful data. That is because some functions call SetLastError with a zero when they succeed, wiping out the error code set by the most recently failed function." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Malfist: Yes, some functions do that. But that doesn't mean it can be done from another thread.

Comment: @Malfist:  This doesn't make `GetLastError()` any more unreliable than anything else.  Those functions aren't going to be magically called.  They are going to be called by something *you do*.  So don't do that until after you've called `GetLastError()`